# Set value in CoreData with three related NSPopUpButton

Tags: xcode, core-data, nsarraycontroller

I hope to express myself with appropriate terms.

I have three entities: *customer*, *country*, *state*. Between *country* and *state*, there are two relationships. So I can create a number of *countries* and select one of these I can create a number of *states* that belong to it.

For creating the interface of the entity "customer" I put three`NSPopUpButton's`:

- The first selects the *country*,
- The second shows the *states* related to the selected *country*.
- The last shows the zip code related to the chosen state.

My problem is that I can not pass data through the chosen`NSPopUpButton` entity "customer". The NSPopoUpButton works by binding:

- Content (bind to:country, arrangedObjects),
- Content Values (bind to:country, arrangedObjects, model key:country),
- Selected Index (bind to:country, selectionIndex).

What can I do to ensure that the data selected by the three `NSPopUpButton's` are recorded in the appropriate fields of the entity "customer"?

Comment: Can you post a bit more code at the View-controller level? To persist changes back to your entity you need to send `save` to the `NSManagedObjectContext` at some point but I suspect you're doing that.

Comment: Do you need to return the managed object, or just return the data in another class that has the data you need?

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that using 3 popups may work with your problem here, as you can return the int for each selected item, and then pass that information on to the next button press.

So, when they press 'country', return back the country id, and put that in your customer entity.

Then, when they press state, pass the country to this popup, and show the states, and pass the state id back, and do the same for city.

This way you don't have lots of managed objects around, as you really don't need the data, you just need the id, and perhaps the name, to show to the user, and these can be passed back in a notification back to your controller.